# can using a decision tree as an index for a column be more efficient than indexing B-Trees?

Tags: database, search, indexing, artificial-intelligence, b-tree

Given that the time complexity to query the database for a column using a B-Tree index is typically O(log(N)), using a decision tree model as a column index could offer better query complexity. time for the same query operations?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, using a decision tree model as a column index will not improve the complexity. B-Trees already offer the optimal time complexity.

Each decision will have two possible outcomes, so when evaluating  conditions you can reach 2 distinct records at the most, not more. So if =2, you'll have to evaluate at least  conditions, which is O(log).